# How to write the formula for rescaling a matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors

I always struggle to express something as a formular.
Given a set of $n$ $5$x$2$ matrices, I want to first write that I rescale every matrix to the range $[0,1]$ where the max and min values are of the current matrix. Second step is to rescale it to $[0,1]$ but now the max and min values are the ones from the entire set of matrices.

Thus, $$P_i = \begin{bmatrix}
(time_1, price_1) \\
(time_2, price_2) \\
(time_3, price_3) \\
(time_4, price_4) \\
(time_5, price_5)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and now I want to rescale it to $P^{S1}_i$:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:Skalierung1}
P^{S1}_i = \frac{P_i - min(P_i)}{max(P_i)-min(P_i)}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
P^{S2}_i = \frac{P_i - min(P)}{max(P)-min(P)}
\end{equation}

How do I make it clear? Or is this sufficient?

Btw: Is $P$ a Matrix or a vector holding two dimensional objects? Does this fact change something? :/

edit:
would that be the squared distance between two matrices (or vectors)?
\begin{equation} 
d(P^{S}_i, P^{S}_j) = \sum_{1=1}^{n}  (P^S_{i} - P^S_{j})^2
\end{equation}